# Download dinamically filtered IR

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I have an application that launches the same IR page from different menus. The IR source is a dynamically filtered table, such as:

```
select *
from my_table
where f_mfilter(:P1_MENU_ID,V('APP_USER'),ROWID) = 'TRUE'
```

When I try to download this IR using Actions->Download I get an empty result with just the header.
How can I get the same result in the downloaded file as I see on the screen?
The APEX version is 21.1.6

Comment: unrelated to this question - using ```V('APP_USER')``` is an unnecessary function call. Within the context of an apex session, in pl/sql or sql the application user can be referenced as ```:APP_USER```. ```V('APP_USER')``` is meant to be used in objects (views/packages/procedures/functions/triggers) only

Answer (score 0):

Have you added P1_MENU_ID to the **Page Items to Submit** attribute of your region? This will make sure that the value is available when the download or any Ajax operation is performed.